# PHP MySQL - Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

I know that there are a tons of related threads but none of them fixes my problem. i'm having a problem connecting to my database. I get the following error:
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

My code for register.php is the following:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //does verification
    $mail1 = $_POST['email1'];
    $mail2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if(($mail1 == $mail2) && ($pass1 == $pass2)){
        //everything is k
        $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
        $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
        $email1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email1']);
        $pass1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);

        $pass1 = md5($pass1);

        //Checks if username is taken
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname'")or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($check)>=1) {
            echo "Username already taken";
        } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `username`, `mail`, `password`, `id`) VALUES ('$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1', NULL)") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Registration Successful";
    } }
    else {
        echo "sorry, something doesn't match.";
    }
} else {
    //displays form
    echo $form = <<<EOT
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br />
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br />
    Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br />
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" />
EOT;
}

?>
```

and my config.php is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("MyDB");
?>
```

What to do? My PHP version is 5.6.27 and MySQL version is 5.6.33

Comment: Where is `user password` ? syntax:
`mysql_connect($server, $username, $password , $dbname)`.Are you sure you are apply the empty password in this `root` user?

Comment: prasad, I didn't change anything at PhpMyAdmin what is regarding MySQL users so the root user has a default password. If I try to log in with password "root", I get the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you should be using `mysqli` functions instead of `mysql` for security reasons, have you checked:

- Your MySQL username is correct?
- That a password is not required?
- The database you are connecting to is correct?

The do:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("MyDB", $db);
```

And your queries should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname'", $db);
```

Comment: Wow, looks like that MySQL default "root" user didn't have an empty or "root" password. I created a new account and then connected. It was school project and they required MySQL and not MySQLi. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd better use mysqli or pdo (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/2660794)

Once you have modified your code, you need to use the credentials you use to connect to database on your server (eg : the one you use for phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using mysqli. For your case, the config.php would look like:

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "MyDB");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connection Failed %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

session_start();
if(isset($SESSION["REMOTE_ADDR"]) && $SESSION["REMOTE_ADDR"] !=     $SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]){
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
?>
```

and instead of "require", you'd do:

```
include ("config.php");
```

Hope this helped